# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting binary data from a SQL Server database field and am creating a document locally in a directory my application has permissions. However I am still getting the error specified in the title. I have tried numerous suggestions posted on the web including those suggested in previous posts on Stackoverflow. I have also used ProcessExplorer > Find Handle to locate the lock and it returns nothing as if the file is not locked.

I am using the code below to save the file to the file system and I then try to copy this file to a new location later in the application process within another method. It is this copy method that takes the path of the newly created file that throws the exception.

The file itself is created with its content and i can open it through Windows Explorer without any problems.

Am I missing something completely obvious? Am I creating the file correctly from the database? Any help on solving or better diagnosing the problem would be much appreciated.

```
// Get file from DB
FileStream fs = new FileStream(
    "C:\myTempDirectory\myFile.doc", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(fs);
br.Write("BinaryDataFromDB");
fs.Flush();
fs.Close();
fs.Dispose();

// Copy file
File.Copy(sourceFileName, destinationFilename, true);
```

Comment: Will you post the actual code? It seems that there is an unseen problem that probably lies hidden elsewhere...

Comment: I know you probably just did a text replacement for the purposes of your question, but your file path should be  `@"C:\myTempDirectory\myFile.doc"` because of backslash escaping.

Comment: Are you sure the exception isn't talking about destinationFilename being in use by another process?

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. Looks like there is a deeper problem which for now gets solved by manually calling GC (which is wrong!! and will get dealt with in the morning!). Code is too bulky to upload hence my cut down version. Thanks again very much appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try adding a call to `GC.Collect()` after you have disposed of your streams to force the garbage collector to clean up.

```
// Get file from DB 
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\myTempDirectory\myFile.doc", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)) 
using(BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(fs))
{
   br.Write("BinaryDataFromDB"); 
   fs.Flush(); 
}

//Force clean up
GC.Collect();

// Copy file 
File.Copy(sourceFileName, destinationFilename, true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to have done it. However something must be wrong somewhere for it to still hold onto it even after I have called close(). Well at least I can move onto the next phase of the issue. Many thanks everybody that helped me get to the bottom of it, much appreciated. I will sleep soundly tonight :)

Comment: Can someone explain why the streams are not closed immediately in Dispose()?

Comment: GC.Collect() => that's EVIL!

Comment: I believe GC.Collect() is evil and should be removed. Also there should be a fs.Close(); after the fs.Flush();

Comment: @AjitGoel The using block calls Dispose on the FileStream and this calls Close(). I think the problem is that this only "flagges" the object for garbage collection and there is a chance that this isn't done before the final line. Calling GC.Collect() forces garbage collection. This isn't a recomendation but a explaination of the problem.

Comment: Why do you need `GC.Collect();`? Makes no sense for me. Dispose should be more than enough.

Answer (score 4):

change your code as follows, the problem is that the the filestream isn't being garbage collected when you need it to:

```
    // Get file from DB 
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\myTempDirectory\myFile.doc", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)) 
{
    BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(fs); 
    br.Write("BinaryDataFromDB"); 
    fs.Flush(); 
    fs.Close(); 
}

// Copy file 
File.Copy(sourceFileName, destinationFilename, true);
```

Comment: No joy unfortunatly!! It should be such a simple thing to do. Thanks again for all your effort guys its much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

What about `using`?

```
string source = @"C:\myTempDirectory\myFile.doc";
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(
    source, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
{
    BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(fs);
    br.Write("BinaryDataFromDB");
}

File.Copy(sourceFileName, destinationFilename, true);
```

**EDIT**: Try to inform a `FileShare.Read` permission.

Comment: What about using on that BinaryWriter ?

Comment: Didnt work im afraid. Even tried it with and without the Close() on the FileStream and BinaryWriter.

Comment: Adding the `FileShare.Read` *seems* to have fixed the issue *for me*

Answer (score 3):

I came to understand that though the error debugger says that the error lies in this code.. But that isn't where the error is.. 
I faced a similar issue and I came with this solution.. consider all the posts above.. 
May be it may help some one..

---

I used the Image to show it in a picturebox after retreiving from Database and saving it as "temp.bmp" using normal coding without using "using" keyword using this code at first:

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("temp.bmp");
```

---

and it raised and error and I really didn't got head and tail of the error.. and so I came up with this solution.

---

Instead of assigning it directly try this code:

```
Bitmap img;
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("temp.bmp"))
{
    img = new Bitmap(bmp);
}
pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

coming to the filestream part I just used normal code as follows:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("filepath",FileMode.Create);
```

and it worked like a piece of cake

---

It really helped

Comment: Thanks Murali. I can see how that would work by assigning the value to a new object and then assigning that objects value which isnt part of the using statement. Thanks for the update and hopefully will be of use to others who come across the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is it that Filestream and BinaryWriter cannot be used at the same time? For instance, a streamwriter and a streamreader cannot both be called on the same file. However, this doesn't make sense, as far as I know, it should not in this case. Perhaps try closing br as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try disposing your BinaryWriter object before doing the copy.

Comment: No luck guys. I did a Flush() and a Close() on the BinaryWriter and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a background process such as antivirus or file-system indexing locking the file just long enough to cause problems with your application? Try pausing for 3 seconds to see if your problem disappears.

```
using System.Threading;

fs.Dispose();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
// Copy file
```

Answer (score 0):

This was what I did:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
var tempStream = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open);
tempStream.CopyTo(stream);
tempStream.Close();
```

then use `stream` object wherever you want.

Answer (score -1):

I seem to encounter this only after I have published an application.  If you close the message box and try again to debug, nothing will happen.
MS Help says to get all the way out of Visual Studio and restart it.  Its easier to bring up Task manager and end the process.  Its name will be the solution name followed by ".vshost"  (e.g. project name: PLC.sln; process name: PLC.vshost.exe).  The process will restart automatically.  In Windows 7 one could usually see something happen when ending a process.  But in 10 the Task Manager window rarely changes.
I get this message when I try testing a program after changing code.  Apparently the .exe is not closed when one stops debugging and the error occurs when VS tries to write a newly complied exe file.  I sometimes have to end the process twice to keep the error message from coming back.  (I have to encounter the error twice; ending the process twice and then rerunning doesn't help.)
This is a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: Try to format your answer. it's hard to read such a big paragraph of text