# Error deploying app to windows phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I am trying to run my app on my windows phone but keep getting the following error.

> `Unexpected error creating debug information file 'c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PhoneApp1\PhoneApp1\obj\Debug\PhoneApp1.PDB' -- 'c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PhoneApp1\PhoneApp1\obj\Debug\PhoneApp1.pdb: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. C:\Users\Admin\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\PhoneApp1\PhoneApp1\CSC    PhoneApp1`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225087/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process

Comment: that is not very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try restarting Visual Studio again, or building your app first using Release configuration and then again using Debug configuration. It will solve your problem.

This is happening because Visual Studio has created a sort of "lock", it can happen sometimes.[image: screenshot of configuration]

Change the debug in the above picture to Release.