# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process when copy and moving file

Tags: c#, .net, file-copying, file-moving

In C# console app I am trying to copy images from one dir to another and then copy the original image from original location to a processed location. I have tried Thread.Sleep etc. but with no luck. Please help!

```
File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath ,true);

File.Move(sourcePath, processedPath);
```

All paths are like `c:\dir\subdir\image1.png` but different subdir locations.

I get the following error

> Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Problem will be somewhere else. Your code doesn't uses reflection at all. Post the relevant code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225087/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process maybe?